# Magento2 - Programatically Increase/Decrease product price by certain amount for all products

Tags: magento2, product, price, magento2.2.4, special-price

I need to `update(increase/decrease)` the `price & special price` by certain amount or percentage for all products in all stores.

Here is the my code but its not `increase/decrease` the price. I have also refered few links but not match with the needs.

```
<?php

error_reporting(1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$updateprice = "100";

$productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
$product = $productFactory->create()->load();
$product->setPrice($updateprice);
$product->save();
?>
```

My version is **Magento 2.2.4**

Can anyone let me know how to `increase/decrease` the price for all products?

Answer (score 0):

try my below code

```
<?php
ob_start();
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

$updateprice = "100";
$storeId = '1'; //Store ID
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$products = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();
foreach ($products as $_product) {
    $price = $_product->getPrice();   
    $getSpecialPrice = $_product->getSpecialPrice(); 
    $_product->setPrice($price + $updateprice);
    $_product->setSpecialPrice($price + $updateprice);
    $_product->save();
}
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I need to increase/decrease the product price by certain amount for all products & all stores. For example if already  product price is 1000 then it should increase by 100 so the final amount after update is 1100

Comment: ok let me check and i will update you

Comment: Thanks,Will check it. It will applies for all products in all Stores? For percentage?

Comment: I have tried above code, added as php file and executed the file but loading for very long and nothing happened.

Comment: Also in backend price updated in wrong logic. For example the same amount is added to special price if the special price don't have value

Comment: For example if I have price as 35 and special price as 25 then it should update the price as 135 and the special price as 125. But currently its showing the same value as 135 for price & special prices. Also Its updated the special as 135 automatically if we don't have special price value.

Comment: then you can add condition `if (spcialpprice){ // getspecialprice}` then add `100`